# iPhone - Sending the app to the background

Tags: iphone, ios, background, settings

In my app, when it runs for the first time, it shows a UIViewAlert and offers you to see the preferences for the app - and the user has 2 choices - yes or no. If the user hits no the alert fades away and the application continues running. I want to set it in such a way, that if the user hits yes, my app will go to the background, the settings tab of the app will be opened (I added a settings bundle to the app). Is it possible to do such a thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. But you can create a settings view in you app and show it instead of trying to open the settings app.

Normally, you do want to encourage users to use your app as long as possible, and making them quit your app yourself is not the best way to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep this in mind, but a settings bundle is more easy to do and more professional, I would say.

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible.
But you could use InAppSettingsKit and modally show a view controller with the settings inside the app.

You can find out more here - http://www.inappsettingskit.com/

Comment: Thanks! I will probably use this! ;-)